# How to convert Matlab time to date in R?

Tags: r, matlab, datetime, for-loop

Sample of my data:

```
 > test_data
      matlab.time            timedate
  1  736148.38577941596         <NA>
  2  736148.38647386897         <NA>
  3  736148.41911317594         <NA>
  4  736148.41980762896         <NA>
  5  736148.42119653604         <NA>
```

I try to convert those matlab times to normal dates with this:

```
  for (i in 1:length(testidata$timedate)) { 
   h <- as.POSIXct((test_data[i,1] - 719529)*86400, origin = "1970-01-01", tz = "UTC")
   test_data[i, 2] <- strftime(h)
  }
```

But the results is

```
     > test_data
      matlab.time            timedate
    1  736148.38577941596 2015-07-03 12:15:31
    2  736148.38647386897                <NA>
    3  736148.41911317594                <NA>
    4  736148.41980762896                <NA>
    5  736148.42119653604                <NA>
```

Why all the matlab times won't be converted?

Comment: should `testidata` be `test_data` (in your for call setup)?

Comment: oops, yes, thanks. It works now

Comment: You should be able to make this code much simpler. as. POSIXct is vectorised - no need to give data one element at a time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your problem may be a typo there, but you can do this a little more simply by getting rid of the for loop.

```
test_data$timedate <- strftime(
    as.POSIXct( ( test_data$matlab.time - 719529) * 86400, 
                origin = "1970-01-01", 
                tz = "UTC")
)
```

This should also be much faster for bigger datasets.